# Is there a way to incude style in a php session?

Tags: php, css, background, background-process

I have a menu that scrolls down and will let you select what color you want for the background, but its only for one page, is there a way to include the style of the page near the beginning of the session so that it will go for all pages?

Comment: What about the index page? Did you well structured you web application ie MVC etc.?

Comment: yes, i just dont know the variable i should use XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a PHP session at the moment?
The call to change the colour of the background should set a session variable.
Any pages being displayed should check the session to see if that variable is present.

Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: hey :D i found a session variable that works, thanks for the guidance to an answer xD  http://php.bigresource.com/use-session-variables-to-pass-the-background-colour-of-a-page-nY3pSVyx.html

Comment: you can use whatever variable you would like. $_SESSION['background_color']. As long as you use the same name to set it and access it.